# How to freeze a port number on Testcontainer's MsSqlContainer?

Tags: docker, integration-testing, testcontainers

I have invested some time in figuring out how to get Testcontainer's MsSqlContainer to spin up for my integration testing... and it works, but... how do you tell the real api what port it's running on if it's random every time?

I feel like I should be able to freeze that value and store it in `appsettings.dev`, agreed?

```cs
    readonly MsSqlContainer _msSqlContainer 
        = new MsSqlBuilder().WithName("MockSqlDb")
                            .WithPortBinding(8081) // Cannot connect to localhost, 8080 
                            .WithExposedPort(8082) // Cannot connect to localhost, 8081 
                            .Build();
    public Task InitializeAsync() 
    { 
        var launchContainerTask = _msSqlContainer.StartAsync();
        launchContainerTask.Wait();

        var cs = _msSqlContainer.GetConnectionString(); // TODO: freeze the port number ? 
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            // setup database, table, and seed data 
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }    
    public Task DisposeAsync() => _msSqlContainer.DisposeAsync().AsTask();
```

Presently I copy-paste the connection string in the middle of debugging (of course I can see it in docker, too).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on a fixed port, you should inject the dynamically mapped random port that is part of the return value of `GetConnectionString()`into your system-under-test. You can find more details on the reasoning behind this in [this best practices article](https://www.atomicjar.com/2023/11/testcontainers-best-practices/) (which has Java examples, but the concept stays the same across languages).

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking there would have had to be an app settings for the test project's server... But you couldn't actually fix this there, because of the silly random stuff.  I have to inject an iconfiguration... And figure out how to get the test class to populate it before the API is looking for it.  This really stinks

Comment: This is the best solution I've found... even the person with the answer admits it's sort of janky:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66789159/simple-and-quick-way-to-change-values-in-appsettings-json-file